# Android - sending extras via PendingIntent

Tags: android, android-intent, widget

I render widget items in a loop after tapping I want to start DetailsActivity (it should send ID to that activity)

```
Cursor currentCursor = dbHelper.getWidgetCursor();
for(int k=0; k < currentCursor.getCount(); k++){
    currentCursor.moveToPosition(k);

    RemoteViews rw = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.w_calendar_item);

    Intent intentRow = new Intent(context, DetailsActivity.class);
    Log.v("a", "index: "+currentCursor.getInt(currentCursor.getColumnIndex(SqlHelper.COLUMN_ID)));
    intentRow.putExtra("index", currentCursor.getInt(currentCursor.getColumnIndex(SqlHelper.COLUMN_ID)));
    PendingIntent pendingIntentRow = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1, intentRow, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    rw.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.w_li, pendingIntentRow);

    views.addView(R.id.w_list, rw);
}
```

My problem is that DetailsActivity always receives index 103 (which is the last on on the list) it doesn't matter which item I tap

Comment: That's because you are *cancelling* the previous pending intent over and over again. Consider generating something "unique" in `intentRow` - e.g. a fake `Uri` passed to `Intent#setData(Uri)` will do the trick - use an incrementing path or some silliness like that.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you set the [PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT) flag in PendingIntent.getActivity. For each row Android will cancel the previous pending intent, so naturally the last one will 'survive'. Perhaps it works by just removing that flag? I don't have any experience with RemoteViews, so not sure what's the best thing to do if that doesn't help.